# Cannot resolve: Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult

Tags: java, android, firebase, play-billing-library

I'm trying to convert android billing version 3 to android billing version 5. But I have a problem in this function, I have no idea how to change it to make it work:

```
@Override
public void onBillingSetupFinished(@NotNull BillingResult billingResult) {
    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        purchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        if (purchasesResult.getPurchasesList() != null &&
                purchasesResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
            for (Purchase purchase : purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()) {
                if (purchase.getSku().equals("premium_upgrade")) {
                    getDataManager().setIsPremium(true);
                    handlePurchase(purchase);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cannot resolve: PurchasesResult, queryPurchases, getPurchasesList...

How can I change this to work in billing 5?